# Mixing dry yeast for NEIPA

Tags: yeast

I have a question did anyone tried to mix Nottingham Ale yeast and Windsor ?
What are the results if you have such an experience?I want to use one pack of each in my NEIPA.I don’t have any other yeast around.

Answer (score 2):

I have not mixed those 2 particular yeasts but I have blended yeasts for previous brews. You basically get 50% of one's charchter and 50% of the others.

If one has a low abv tolerance/attenuation and the other higher then you should use the higher value to calculate the final ABV, and the body you would expect to be left.

Example, 50/50 S-04/US-05:

- You get less ester falvour that you would get from 100% S-04.
- You get the same thinner crisper body you would expect from US05.
- You get the final ABV expected from US05.

Comment: Thank you , I will try to go 50/50 this time.Hope to get body from Windsor and ABV from Notti.

Answer (score 1):

Just finished my third NEIPA brew with a 50/50 Nottingham / Windsor blend. Not a ton of fruity esters at 68 degrees, but produces a nice flavor for the style. The FG is always a bit lower than Brewsmith predictions for the yeasts. Go for it!

Comment: Thanx man, great to know!